# Getting the right data from webpage

Tags: web-scraping, comments, extract, export-to-excel

I am looking to extract some data from website:

http://www.delfi.lv/bizness/biznesa_vide/tirgus-liberalizacija-ka-latvija-nonaca-krievijas-gazes-juga.d?id=44233361&com=1&s=5

from me it's valuable to get info like:

```
"<h3 class="ca56269332 comment-noavatar listh3 comment-noavatar-author">
vārds
</h3>"
```

In this example "ca56269332" and "vārds" are dynamic variables.

For me I want to achieve something like this:

```
"<h3 class="* comment-noavatar listh3 comment-noavatar-author">
*
</h3>"
```

where "*" means a dynamic value, and export in some kind of excel or data file.

Also I want to extract multiple pages, like:

/tirgus-liberalizacija-ka-latvija-nonaca-krievijas-gazes-juga.d?id=44233361&com=1&s=5&no=0
/tirgus-liberalizacija-ka-latvija-nonaca-krievijas-gazes-juga.d?id=44233361&com=1&s=5&no=20
/tirgus-liberalizacija-ka-latvija-nonaca-krievijas-gazes-juga.d?id=44233361&com=1&s=5&no=40

ect.

Can anyone please share some valuable resources to achieve that, I know that you can make it with PHP file_get but I want easier solution because my goal is not to publish it to webpage but use as source for my study project as a data file.

How to EXTRACT dynamic data to AVOID saving EVERY page with ALL the useless information it contains and make it easier, avoiding to manually process large number of web comments?

Comment: Essentially you need to A) use a DOM parser, and B) identify in some way the specific DOM element(s) you want to extract.

Comment: What language would you use? This is too broad... decide which language you're going to use and then look up how to parse DOM for that language. As it is there are thousands of answers already out there